# How to delete a local disk with a question mark?

Tags: windows-7

In my computer I have a local disk Y with a blue question mark. Tried to delete it, but it shows a message that says:

> Y:\ refers to a location that is unavailable. It could be on a hard
>   drive on this computer, or on a network. Check to make sure that the
>   disk is properly inserted, or that you are connected to the Internet
>   or your network, and then try again. If it still cannot be located,
>   the information might have been moved to a different location.

I've run Avast to see if there is a virus, but it didn't detect anything.

I have Windows 7. Please note that I'm not a super experienced user.

I really don't have any idea how to fix this.

Please help

Comment: You want to delete which one `that blue question mark` or `that local disk` ? And How ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Its very unlikely you have a detected storage device reader without any storage accessible to your computer or as the message indicates a storage location that isn't accessible..

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you found your answer yet. I have the same issue. It
s just a device you may have connected or drive installed. Now that its disconnected. It shows with a question mark. I had to troubleshoot my Fire Tablet to get it to work for my PC. So it gave me the ? after I disconnected. Hope this helps.

Comment: So what is the answer to the question of how to delete the disk?